# Getting keyword times from pocketsphinx without logs

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to use `pocketsphinx` for some keyword recognition. I'm able to use `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile -keyphrase` and `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile -kws` successfully. The output seems quite verbose and I'm unable to find a guide or a parser on the internet. My output requirement is to just get the time stamps at which the keyword was recognised. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to just print the times:

```
  pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -keyphrase "hello world" \
      -logfn /dev/null -time yes
```

`-logfn` option suppress logs, `-time` option enables printing the times. Times are in seconds.

Comment: Thanks! Is there still some guide to the output though? I see output along these lines which I don't fully understand (I assumed word: time1, time2, time3, etc. is what it was supposed to be but I don't think that's the case)  - word1  
word1   5.060 5.560 1.041336
word2   word3  
word2   7.860 8.140 1.017249
word3   7.600 7.830 1.036142
word2  
word2   24.330 24.690 1.014404

Comment: First the keyphrase, then start time in seconds, end time in seconds and confidence